# mod rewrite RewriteRule always directs to index.php when it shouldn't

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've tested this problem out on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, but when I do it on my local ubuntu apache webserver, it fails.

The request is:

http://example.com/creator/main/narwhal

My .htaccess file, which works for other commands, is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^creator/main/([^/.]+)/?$ /about.html [L]
```

For some reason, the result I get back is:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 68.56.177.238 Port 8080

There is no instance of index.php in my .htaccess file, so why is it trying to redirect there? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check your Apache config if you have a rewrite rule there.

Comment: No reference to index, or index.php in them.

Comment: Please paste the entire contents in htaccess file.

Comment: Figured it out. There was another htaccess file in a subdirectory that screwed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Got this one. There was another htaccess file in a subdirectory that caused the weird redirect.